# Servers upgraded, NFS not working as well

Tags: debian, nfs

I administer two servers that were set up by a previous admin, one works as an NFS server the other the client and they have a dedicated 10GBase-T connection. Both servers were recently upgraded from Debian 8 to 11 per a requirement from management. The upgrades showed no errors that were TCP/IP or NFS related and before the upgrade the NFS connection was seemingly stable. After the upgrade it is no longer as stable with file access not working consistently. A check of the logs on the server shows two error messages.

`rpc-srv/tcp: nfsd: got error -104 when sending 24 bytes - shutting down socket`
`rpc-srv/tcp: nfsd: got error -32 when sending 24 bytes - shutting down socket`

The -32 error shows up far more often than the -104 error. A check of the historical logs before the upgrade show the same errors though at a slightly less frequency.

Hoping for any assistance with this. A search found very few -32 errors in various forums, none solved, and some solved -104 errors but mostly via upgrades to an nfs-server version that has been superseded since then.

EDIT follows

Some generic searching on NFS issues led me to check the nfsstat and netstat output. Here is both.

```
root@nfsserver:~# nfsstat -r
Server rpc stats:
calls        badcalls   badfmt     badauth    badclnt
2570111375   63390961   0          63390961   0
root@nfsserver:~# netstat -i
Kernel Interface table
Iface      MTU       RX-OK RX-ERR  RX-DRP RX-OVR        TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
eth0      1500 13992642607      0 6728159      0   2417486300      0      0      0 BMRU
eth1      9000 12890945209      0       0      0  12332795301      0      0      0 BMRU
lo       65536      212459      0       0      0       212459      0      0      0 LRU
```

Note that the interface used by NFS is eth1. While the rpc stats look like a bad network connection there are no errors seen on the interface itself. Checking netstat -s on both client and server shows some errors though.

A known good NIC was installed and configured and an STP CAT6A cable used with the same results. The interfaces on both ends have been set to the same MTU, 9000.

The NFS exports have the following options: rw,async,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check
The NFS mounts have the following options in fstab: nfsvers=3,rw,async,hard,intr,_netdev
The NFS mounts show the following options in mount: rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=192.168.0.1,mountvers=3,mountport=55838,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.0.1,_netdev
These options are used successfully on other NFS servers and clients with the same OS. I have already attempted to define rsize and wsize with no change.

I'm at my whits end with this one and am hoping an NFS genius is around to help out.

Comment: I will assume, that `-32` is `broken pipe` and `-104` is `connection reset`. To me sounds like network issue (firewall that drops idle connections?)

Comment: The servers are directly connected via 10GBase-T. There is no firewall or other device between them.